# Java Image Generation Of Heat Map for Google Earth

Tags: java, google-earth, heatmap, geotools, jak

I'm working on a Java program that processes some data and generates a Heat Map to display the results. This program takes a target area and divides that area into a grid, which for the sake of testing each cell is 1NM by 1NM. I generate a KML file and that for each cell in the grid is represented by a polygon and the polygon is coloured based on the value of the cell. However with the volume of data that may be used, I am worried that Google Earth may not be able to handle the amount of polygons being drawn(hundreds of polygons).

I have heard that pictures are less resource heavy for Google Earth, so is there a way of generating a image(like .jpg or .png) in Java of the Heat Map and overlaying it in Google Earth. The center of the cell is know and the 4 corners are calculated, with each cells RGB and hex value known. I'm using Geotools and JAK as libraries for this project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some GeoTools based code that generates heat map images at http://code.google.com/p/spatial-cluster-detection/ - there is code in there that will show you how to convert your grid into georeferenced imagery.

Comment: If it is all possible, which Class handels the georeferenced imagery?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/spatial-cluster-detection/source/browse/trunk/cluster/src/main/java/org/geotools/clustering/QuantizeCircle.java

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible, and that's as far as I can go with an answer with the information provided on the question.

However, if you already have your `.kml` created, it's worth a try testing it to see if Google Earth will really go crazy of if you are just speculating.

Comment: I was able to get input from members of another project that is using Google Earth, and they found that once the Polygon count got into the thousands that Google Earth became slow. That is why I was worried about this as this program will have simmular number of polygons. Can you point out where I can learn to generated these images?

Comment: If you are going with the default Java API, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) is a good start.